# Node, Express, case study: "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express

My server crashed and I found the following error in my logs:

```
   Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

and I could not reproduce the error. I think I found a fix, but I want to ensure that I understand the problem, which is outlined in the code below. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent), I believe it is coming from the multiple `res.send(..)` calls in my Express router:

```
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
    var msg = '(message okay)'
    var db = req.db;    
    db.collection('userlist').find({
        username: req.body.username;
    }).toArray(function(err, items) {

        // verify the user, set session fields, etc...

        console.log("message after user verification is: ");
        console.log(msg);

        res.send({
            msg: msg
        });

    });

    // Insert the request's data into the 'userlist' collection.
    db.collection('userlist').insert(body, function(err, result) {
        console.log("inserting into userlist...");
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? {
                msg: msg
            } : {
                msg: err
            }
        );
    });
    console.log("message after user verification is: ");
    console.log(msg);
}
```

The last few lines of my log are:

```
message after user verification is: 
(message okay)
POST /login/adduser 200 7ms - 10b
inserting into userlist...

/home/lucas/mynode/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/c
onnection/base.js:245
        throw message;      
              ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
 at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
 at ServerResponse.header (/home/lucas/mynode/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:717:10)
 at ServerResponse.send
```

I suspect that I am calling the `res.send(..)` twice, so I believe that I fixed this by removing the first `res.send(..)`, but is this the correct fix? Also, if calling `res.send(..)` twice causes the error, then why can't I reproduce this bug? I never got the error, but another user did.

Can anyone provide an explanation? Feedback on my solution would also be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's due to the multiple uses of `res.send()`. Express' `res.send()` finalizes the response to the web client  via [`res.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding). Once the response has been ended, no further output should/can be written until a new `req` arrives with its own `res`.

Comment: Note, it looks like you may also have a race condition between two async operations and there is no guarantee of order.  If you want to make sure the second db operation happens after the first one, then you need to manually sequence them by not starting the second one until the first one is done or by not inserting the result from the second one until the first one is done.

Comment: Recently I was also having the same problem. I had used res.set("Connection", "close"); after res.json() ... and that was the problem. I removed the res.set and wolla, its working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should restructure your code, atm you have got 2 async calls in your code

```
db.collection('userlist').find is called and will return later
db.collection('userlist').insert and will also return later
```

so you call res.send 2 times

something like this and you won't call res.send twice

```
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
  var msg = '(message okay)'
  var db = req.db;

  db.collection('userlist').find({username: req.body.username}).toArray(function(err, items) {
    // verify the user, set session fields, etc...
    // if error return(send) error
    if(err) return res.send({err:"errormessage"})
    // if everything is ok - Insert the request's data into the 'userlist' collection.
    db.collection('userlist').insert(body, function(err, result) {
      //if error return(send)  error
      if(err) return res.send({err:err})
      //everything was ok send msg
      res.send({msg:msg})
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the *cause* of the problem, however, there isn't enough information here to determine whether the solution is the correct one.

For example, there is no obvious relationship from the example between the `find` / `insert` calls - are these supposed to be called in series? Does `insert` require anything from the `find`? For example, if you need to check a record exists *before* inserting then the correct solution would look something like

```
db.collection('userlist').findOne({
    username: req.body.username
}, function(err, result) {
    if (result !== null) {
        db.collection('userlist').update(result, body, function(err, updateCount) {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log('Updated existing record');
            }
        });
    } else {
        db.collection('userlist').insert(body, function(err, result) {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log('Created new record');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Notice the difference here?
Remember, `find` and `insert` are *non-blocking* calls so in your example you can't guarentee the order of which both callbacks are run. However, by moving the `insert` call into the `find` callback we are guarenteeing that `insert` will always be called *after* the `find`.